# Combining react-leaflet and leaflet-pixi-overlay

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, pixi.js, react-leaflet

I am trying to display a complex map with many moving markers, with different icons etc... I have a pure react / react-leaflet solution, but it start to struggle with ~1k markers moving every second.

It looks like leaflet-pixi-overlay could be a way of really speeding things up. But I am just starting with the whole chain (react/javascript/maps/leaflet/etc..) and have problems when connecting all this.

Right now I am just trying to display a polygon in my overlay, and nothing is rendered. It turns out that the translation of lat/long to x/y is failing for that polygon's points. Pixi's latLngToLayerPoint function returns 'infinity' for x and y.

This seems to come from the fact that the zoom is not defined for the layer in question (it is 'infinity' also).

Even if I call latLngToLayerPoint with the zoom setting from the map, things fail too (x/y values are not infinite any more, but they are way out there).

This is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"

import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'
import 'leaflet-pixi-overlay'       // Must be called before the 'leaflet' import
import L from 'leaflet';

let polyLatLngs = [[50.630, 13.047], [50.645, 13.070], [50.625, 13.090], [50.608, 13.070], [50.630, 13.047]]

let pixiContainer = new PIXI.Container()
let prevZoom
let firstDraw = true;
let projectedPolygon;
var shape = new PIXI.Graphics();
pixiContainer.addChild(shape);

let myOverlay = L.pixiOverlay(function (utils) {
    let map = utils.getMap()
    let zoom = map.getZoom()
    console.log('map zoom=' + zoom + ', center=' + map.getCenter())
    console.log('   bounds=' + JSON.stringify(map.getBounds()))
    console.log('   size=' + map.getSize() + ', panes=' + JSON.stringify(map.getPanes()))
    if (map) {
        var container = utils.getContainer();
        var renderer = utils.getRenderer();
        var project = utils.latLngToLayerPoint;
        var scale = utils.getScale();

        if (firstDraw) {
            projectedPolygon = polyLatLngs.map((coords, index) => {
                console.log('i=' + index + ', coords=' + coords + ', proj=' + project(coords))                
                return project(coords)            
                // return project(coords, zoom)  // : this fails too
            })
        }
        if (firstDraw || prevZoom !== zoom) {
            shape.clear();
            shape.lineStyle(3 / scale, 0x3388ff, 1);
            shape.beginFill(0x3388ff, 0.2);
            projectedPolygon.forEach(function (coords, index) {
                if (index === 0) shape.moveTo(coords.x, coords.y);
                else shape.lineTo(coords.x, coords.y);
            });
            shape.endFill();
        }
        firstDraw = false;
        prevZoom = zoom;
        renderer.render(container);
    }
}, pixiContainer)

function PxMap(props) {
    const mapRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (mapRef.current !== null) {
            let map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;
            console.log('useEffect: add overlay ')
            console.log(JSON.stringify(map.getPane('overlayPane').childElementCount))
            myOverlay.addTo(map);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(map.getPane('overlayPane').childElementCount))
        }
    }, [mapRef]);

    return (
        <div style={{ flexgrow: 1, height: '100%' }}>
            <Map
                preferCanvas={true}
                ref={mapRef}
                style={{ height: '100%' }}
                center={[50.63, 13.047]}
                zoom={12}
            >
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?"
                />
            </Map>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PxMap
```

I think that things are connected correctly between React and leaflet, the map displays ok, I can see the overlay being added etc...

BUT there is a connection missing somewhere, to give more context / information to PIXI.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the problem, drilling down into the leaflet-pixi-overlay lib.

The solution is to define the minZoom and maxZoom in the Map element:

```
        <Map
            preferCanvas={true}
            ref={mapRef}
            style={{ height: '100%' }}
            center={[50.63, 13.047]}
            zoom={12}
            minZoom={ 9}  // Add these options...
            maxZoom={ 16} //
```

Internally, L.PixiOverlay.js relies on these two values to define:

```
// return the layer projection zoom level
projectionZoom: function (map) {return (map.getMaxZoom() + map.getMinZoom()) / 2;},
```

Which in turn is used to define the default zoom setting?

```
this._initialZoom = this.options.projectionZoom(map);
....
zoom = (zoom === undefined) ? _layer._initialZoom : zoom;
var projectedPoint = map.project(L.latLng(latLng), zoom);
```

Not sure why this is done this way, but setting these options solves the problem.